# Converting a vector to a vector of standard units in R

Tags: r

Is there a function in R that given a vector of numbers, returns another vector with the standard units corresponding to each value?

where...
standard unit: how many SDs a value is + or - from the mean

Example:

```
 x <- c(1,3,4,5,7)    # note: mean=4, sd=2
 su(x) 
 [1]  -1.5  -0.5  0.0  0.5  1.5
```

Is this func already included in a package?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the scale function.

```
?scale
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked.  I'm a new user and not allowed yet to mark it as the correct answer.

Comment: @jd01 Glad it helped. You should be able to accept it by clicking on the check mark if you like; I don't think it takes any rep to accept an answer to your own question.

Comment: @jd01 I gave you a +1 on your question so that you could even upvote the answer you ticked as the one which solved your problem.

Comment: note: importing a couple of useful notes from stackoverflow: in my example I'm using the complete population's SD (2), not the sample SD (2.23); Ah, well then you should say so in your Q, because the scale() answers will only work if you do: scale(x, center=4, scale=2)

Comment: @chl: thanks - upvoted jms' answer as soon as i got enough reputation.

Comment: In re: population vs sample SD, the only real benefit of scale(x) where the input x is a vector and not a matrix is that it calculates mean/sd for you. If you calculate the sd separately or have it in hand, (x-mean(x))/2 will do the same.